# ChartJS: two axes in horizontalBar chart

Tags: chart.js

Using a standard bar chart I am able to successfully create a chart with two datasets plotted on two y-axis. Working Example here: https://jsfiddle.net/pe8kxjqc/12/ How can I create the same chart as a horizontalBar chart with the labels on the left and the two dataset axes on the top and bottom?

The horizontalBar chart doesn't appear to handle the second axis as expected. I've tried the following but it doesn't work like expected:

```
var data = {
labels: ["Label1", "Label2", "Label3", "Label4", "Label5"],
datasets: [
{
   "label": "Total V",
   "xAxisID": "v",
   "backgroundColor": "rgba(53,81,103,1)",
   "borderColor": "rgba(53,81,103,.4)",
   "data": [100,90,80,70,60]
},
{
   "label": "Total C",
   "xAxisID": "c",
   "backgroundColor": "rgba(255,153,0,1)",
   "borderColor": "rgba(255,153,0,.4)",
   "data": [10,9,8,7,6]
}]};

var options = {scales:{
xAxes:[
   {position:"top",id:"v", gridLines:{color:"rgba(53,81,103,.4)"}},
   {position:"bottom",id:"c", gridLines:{color:"rgba(255,153,0,.4)"}}
]}};

var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
new Chart(ctx, {type: "horizontalBar",data:data, options:options});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have dynamic configuration for `bar` as well as `horizontalBar` you can use this configurations

[Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/rkh6f3L0/)

```
var data = {
  labels: ["Label1", "Label2", "Label3", "Label4", "Label5"],
  datasets: [{
    "label": "Total V",
    "yAxisID": "A",
    "backgroundColor": "rgba(53,81,103,1)",
    "borderColor": "rgba(53,81,103,.4)",
    "data": [100, 90, 80, 70, 60]
  }, {
    "label": "Total C",
    "yAxisID": "A",
    "backgroundColor": "rgba(255,153,0,1)",
    "borderColor": "rgba(255,153,0,.4)",
    "data": [10, 9, 8, 7, 6]
  }]
};

var options = {
  scales: {
    yAxes: [{
      id: 'A',
      position: 'left'
    }]
  }
};

var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
new Chart(ctx, {
  type: "horizontalBar",
  data: data,
  options: options
});
```

coming to your question the actual problem is with  `var options={...}` it is made to work only with `bar` charts. Hope you understand

**Update**

Replace following as `option` in the chart above for required axis scales

```
var options = {scales:{yAxes:[{id: 'A',position: 'left',gridLines:{color:"rgba(53,81,103,.4)"}},{position:"top",id:"c", gridLines:{color:"rgba(255,153,0,.4)"},ticks: { min: 0,max: 100,}},]}};
```

[updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rkh6f3L0/2/)

Comment: @Deep_3015 - I appreciate your reply but your solution doesn't address the issue of multiple axes. If you look at my included fiddle example you'll see two different scales to the right and left of the chart. In a horizontalBar chart this should translate to 'top' and 'bottom' with the labels on the left

Comment: @Deep_3015 - Thank you. Your updated solution does create the second axis labels. Unfortunately the original issue still remains in that there should be two scales - the blue bars from 0-100 and the yellow bars from 0-10 and they should be the same length despite being different values. Currently both datasets are still being plotted on the same yAxis (yAxisID: 'A')

Answer (score 0):

Basically you will need a y-axis for the first dataset which going to hold the labels. And you will need two x-axis for showing the values in the top and in the bottom.

The second dataset will go to the x-axis which is shown at the top.

Working fiddle included:

```
{
  scales: {
    yAxes: [{
      id: 'A',
      position: 'left',
      display: true,
      gridLines: {
        color: "rgba(53,81,103,.4)"
      }
    }, ],
    xAxes: [{
      barPercentage: 0.4,
      display: true,
      id: "1",
      position: 'bottom',
      ticks: {
        fontColor: 'rgb(0, 0, 0)'
      },
      fontSize: 500,
    }, {
      stacked: false,
      barPercentage: 1,
      display: true,
      type: 'linear',
      id: '2',
      position: 'top',
      ticks: {
        fontColor: 'rgb(0, 0, 0)'
      },
      fontSize: 500,
    }],
  }
};
```

[fiddle for two axis horizontal bar chart](https://jsfiddle.net/5q0Lg21d/)